# How to debug "Error: Promise rejected with no or falsy reason" in Mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, chai

I have a test failing in Mocha with this error.

I have put `catch` statements at the end of every promise's chain that throw any error they are passed but they are never called.

And yet the test keeps failing with the following error:

```
Error: Promise rejected with no or falsy reason
  at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:507:31)
  at Promise._settlePromiseAt (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
  at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
  at Async._drainQueue (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
  at Async._drainQueues (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
  at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
```

How do I find out what the problem is exactly, which promise gets rejected and get a more meaningful trace?

Comment: It would help to include your test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what triggered the error. I had to promisify a stream so I wrapped it in a `return new Promise...`

However, promises have a different signature from regular callbacks. An error comes first in a callback: `function(err, res) { ... }`. In promises, it's the opposite: `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... }`.

I had `new Promise(function(reject, resolve) { ... }`. As such, I was calling `resolve` when the stream finished and `reject` when the stream had an error. However, my `resolve` was actually the `reject` function and my `reject` was actually the `resolve` function because I inverted them.

Comment: Thanks that was my issue.

In Promise signature  resolve first, reject second

Comment: Maybe you can use here bluebirds `Promisify` or `PromisifyAll` functions which will cast callbacks into promises - see: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html